# Best Performance - emit to sockets via a loop or rooms

Tags: socket.io

We currently have a chat app whereby when emitting messages out to the appropriate users (could be 1 or several depending how many are in the conversation) we loop through all socket (Socket.io 2.0.2) connections to the server (NodeJS) to get a list of sockets that a user has based on a member ID value as each user could be connected from multiple devices.  The code looks like this in order to determine which sockets a user has that we should be sending the message,

```
    var sockets = Object.keys(socketList);
    var results = [];
    for (var key in sockets) {
        if (hasOwnProperty(socketList[sockets[key]].handshake.query, 'token')) {
            if (JSON.parse(socketList[sockets[key]].handshake.query.member).id === memberId) {
                results.push(socketList[sockets[key]]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Having to loop through the socket connections seems inefficient and I wonder is there a better way.  My thought is to create a room for each user, most users will have only the one connection but some will be connected via multiple devices so they could have multiple sockets in their room.  Then I would just broadcast to the appropriate rooms rather than always looping through all sockets.  Given that 95% of users will only have the one socket connection I'm not sure if this approach is any more efficient or not and would appreciate some input on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, socket.io already creates a room for every single user.  That room has the name of the `socket.id`.  Rooms are very lightweight objects.  They basically just consist of an object with all the ids of the sockets that are in the room.  So, there should be no hesitancy to use rooms at all.  If they fit the model of what you're doing, then use them.

As for looping yourself vs. emitting to a room, there's really no difference - use whichever makes your code simpler.  When you emit to a room, all it does is loop through the sockets in the room and send to each one individually.

> Having to loop through the socket connections seems inefficient and I wonder is there a better way.

The main advantage of rooms is that they are pre-built associations of sockets so you don't have to dynamically figure out which sockets you want to send to - there's already a list of sockets in the right room that you can send to.  So, it would likely be a small bit more efficient to just send to all sockets in a room than to do what your code is doing because you code is dynamically trying to figure out which sockets to send to, rather than sending to an already made list.  Would this make a difference?  That depends upon how long the whole list of sockets is and how expensive the computation is to figure out which ones you want to send to.  My guess is that it probably wouldn't make much difference either way.

Sending a message to a room is not much more efficient on the actual sending part.  Each socket has to be sent the message individually so somebody (your code or the socket.io rooms code) is going to be looping through a list of sockets either way.  The underlying OS does not contain a function to send a single message to multiple sockets.  Each socket has to be sent to individually.

> Then I would just broadcast to the appropriate rooms rather than always looping through all sockets.

Sending to a room is a programming convenience for you, but socket.io will just be looping under the covers anyway.

Comment: is the takeway from this that if you would like to send to multiple sockets from the *server*, it is just as reasonable to loop over an array of socket id string's and send to each of their individual *rooms* with `socket.to('${socketId}').emit('hey', 'message to a socket's room');` as it is to loop over the same array and send to their individual *sockets* with `io.to('${socketId}').emit('hey', 'message to a socket');`?  i am referencing https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet , thank you.

Comment: @user1063287 - From a networking point of view, it doesn't matter whether you iterate manually and send to each or whether you let socket.io do it for you.  Either way, it's the same number of separate transmissions.  So, any performance difference would only be in how each piece of code iterates a list and differences would likely be insignificant.  FYI, you don't need `socket.to('${socketId}').emit(...)`.  You can just do `socket.to(socketId).emit(...)`.

Comment: when you say `let socket.io do it for you`, you still need to iterate over an array of socket id’s though don’t you? so you can send to each socket id based room? (this is in the scenario where users are *only* in the default socket id based room they join when connecting)

Comment: @user1063287 - Letting socket.io means broadcasting to all via `io.emit()` or using rooms to manage collections of users and letting socket.io send to them with `io.to()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Wouldn't his example actually be a bit slower? In the source code you linked to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093554/room-broadcast-vs-sockets-emit-are-they-the-same/40095278#40095278 it encodes the message just one time while his syntax would encode it many times. Just wanted to mention that. You did mention the networking point of view, but overall broadcast would be slightly more efficient in that specific scenario.

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin - Yes, from the standpoint of server CPU efficiency to send all the messages that's true since you would save a bit of encoding work (though I don't know how noticeable the difference would be).  From the standpoint of the network, it's the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Socket.io rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) to accomplish what you want to do.

Server side, adding a client to a chat room:

```
socket.join('some room');
```

Then I would use `socket.to('some room').emit` for a sender message to be sent to all participants in the room.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there any conerns about resource usage for socket.io to create and maintain a room for each user?

Comment: Not a large number, about 10,000.