# Using socket.io is broadcasting the same efficiency as sending a message to every client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to optimize some code, a node server, sending messages to many clients. Right now it broadcasts to *all* clients even when it only needs to send messages to a fraction of them. There's no harm in this in terms of correctness, but the server is struggling to deal with so many messages in terms of efficiency. I'm considering writing some code to make sure it only sends to the clients that need it. However, I'm not sure if this is much more efficient or not.

Supposing that sending a message takes X computation. Suppose there are N clients connected. Does broadcasting then take N*X total computation? Or perhaps is broadcasting optimized so the computation is less? That's my question.

Just for the sake of defining what I mean by broadcast and single message, here's a bit of code. Note that this code is only to define the operations clearly:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone'}); // broadcast
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' }); // single message
});
```

Comment: It may or may not be more efficient. IMHO, the __best__ way to be sure is to test it is to __benchmark it yourself__.

I would say that sending a single message is less expensive that broadcast it, but it may not be true that sending multiple messages to almost everyone is less expensive that broadcasting, because broadcasting may be optimised.

Comment: This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but I have not really loved working with socket.io since it has a really hard time scaling. It requires a lot of work to get it to work with load balancers. The other thing is that socket.io is really heavy since it does a lot to make sure it works with all browsers. After a lot of research I found a framework that works way better in production. http://socketcluster.io/#!/ It is easy to configure concurrency and is easy to to scale up and out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadcasting to either all connected clients or to all clients in a room is nothing more than sending an individual message to each of the clients.  The "broadcast" semantics in the socket.io API is an API convenience only.  It is no more efficient than (or different from) sending a message yourself to each of the same clients.

> Supposing that sending a message takes X computation. Suppose there are N clients connected. Does broadcasting then take N*X total computation?

Yes, it does.  It will be N*X.  The computation is mostly the TCP socket overhead of sending the message and receiving back the TCP packet confirmation.  There is a small amount of CPU overhead in creating the webSocket packet, but not much.  If you're running over SSL, then there will be some crypto overhead too.

> Or perhaps is broadcasting optimized so the computation is less?

No, it's still a loop sending to each individual client.  Doing your own loop may be marginally more of less efficient than the loop built into socket.io's `.broadcast()`, but likely won't differ much.

The best way to make your code more efficient is to only send to the clients that actually need the message.

---

To see a reference on the actual `.broadcast()` socket.io code that loops, see this answer: [room broadcast vs sockets emit - are they the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093554/room-broadcast-vs-sockets-emit-are-they-the-same/40095278#40095278).  And, another similar question: [Best Performance - emit to sockets via a loop or rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845687/best-performance-emit-to-sockets-via-a-loop-or-rooms/44855403#44855403).